# Shift-control-F on a Python file in VS Code does not work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I type <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> in VS Code, I get an error message: "There is no formatter for 'python' files installed."
I want automatic line alignment.

Comment: Have you tried the options here? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

1. Open the Extensions view by clicking on the Extensions icon in the Activity  Bar on the side of the window or using the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+X.
   2.Search for "Python" in the Extensions view search box.
   3.Look for an extension that provides Python formatting. One popular choice is "Python" by Microsoft.
2. Install the extension.

Once installed, you should be able to use Shift+Alt+F to format your Python code automatically.